# Jquery Animate Sin wave step method

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kpj3b/19/

It starts off all right, but then quickly becomes erratic and violent.   I am just looking to make a nice smooth sin wave from point A to point B.

Any suggestions in my Mathmatics?

```
$("#ball").stop().animate({'border-spacing': 400 },{ 
    step: function(p, fx) {
        s = Math.sin(p);
        y = s * 50 + 150;
        console.log(s);
        var move = {top: y + "px", left: p + "px"};
        $(fx.elem).css(move);
    }, duration: 10000, complete: function () { $("#ball").remove(); }
});
```

PS: I am trying not to use jquery.path.js.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify `easing`, it will default to `'swing'`, which is why it looks progressively more "violent."  You can specify `'linear'` for easing to get more of the effect you desire.  I also updated the *amount* that the `border-spacing` property changes because when it's so high the tweens are a bit too separate for the eye:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Kpj3b/20/

Comment: The border-spacing property allows you to set the X as which you wish it to travel.  It's odd that it becomes violent again when you simply adjust how far you wish it to travel.  Also if you lower the duration it again becomes a violent mess.  I was hoping to avoid using jquery.path.

Comment: @Iscariot - you can slow down the bounce and make it less violent by dividing the number you send into sin(). Example: `s = Math.sin(p/20);` will slow down the bounce considerably: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpj3b/36/